# Why visual studio needs a static library (.lib) for dynamic linking?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I want to use some dll in my project ( VS2013 - c++ ),

I gave the path of dll and headers using "project->properties->vc++ directories", and after building the project, linker errors (common "unresolved external symbol") appears. the problem can be solved by giving the .lib file to the linker!

But why static library (.lib) is needed for dynamic linking???

Comment: That's how dynamic linking works on Windows. Google terms: "import library", "def file", "__declspec(dllimport)"

Comment: This has already been comprehensively answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an import library, which contains definitions of exports, that resides inside `DLL` and name of that `DLL` **(*)**.

> You can use `LIB` with the `/DEF` option to create an import library and an export file. `LINK` uses the export file to build a program that contains exports (usually a dynamic-link library (`DLL`)), and it uses the import library to resolve references to those exports in other programs.

And also:

> In most situations, you do not need to use `LIB` to create your import library. When you link a program (either an executable file or a `DLL`) that contains exports, `LINK` automatically creates an import library that describes the exports. Later, when you link a program that references those exports, you specify the import library.

Dynamic libraries are loaded at runtime (on application startup) - linker does not check where some particular symbol resides in `DLL`. `Header` says `__dllimport` - "this symbol is an extern, it should be imported from somewhere". `Lib` says "I know where this symbol is - it resides in `XXX.dll`, so look there after startup".

---

**(*)** I saw a lot of people, that were trying to change names of `.lib` and corresponding `.dll` and expected, that it will work. Contents of `.lib` is the reason why it didn't.

Comment: So is there any way to use a dll without corresponding lib file in VS ??
(can visual studio extract all info from dll itself?? just like GNU Linker??)

Comment: @payman Better late than never - yes, [there is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946390/2170527).

Answer (score 4):

- To tell it the name of the DLL and what's in it, and what the entry pioint numbers are if used, and
- to isolate the binary interface (the .lib) from its implementation (the DLL). Winsock for example had a standard .lib file which was independent of the actual multi-vendor implementations, back in the day.

Comment: So what to do when we just have the dll file? I think that all info about the library (name, exports, entry point,...) can be extracted from dll itself?!

Comment: You can create the .lib file from the DLL.