# create MSVC import library with MinGW tools

Tags: visual-c++, cross-compiling, mingw-w64, import-libraries

We are currently switching the W32 build-process of a cross-platform (linux, osx, w32) project from VisualStudio to mingw.

One of the problems we are facing is, that our projects creates a dynamic library (`foo.dll`), against which 3rd party projects can link. For this to work on W32/MSVC, an import library is required (`foo.lib`).

Now, following [the documentation](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls) it is pretty easy to create a .def file which holds all the information required for importing the library:

```
 gcc -shared -o foo.dll foo-*.o -Wl,--output-def,foo.def
```

In order to use the `foo.def` file, the docs tell me to use the *Microsoft LIB* tool to build a `foo.lib` from it:

```
 lib /machine:i386 /def:testdll.def
```

This obviously requires me to have (a subset of) MSVC installed on the build computer.
However, we'd like to cross-compile the entire thing on our linux systems (probably even on some CI), which makes the installation of MSVC rather tedious.

So I wonder, whether there's a native MinGW way to convert the `foo.def` file into a `foo.lib` import library?

(We are aware that in the end, only MSVC users will *require* the import library and that they will have the `lib` tool ready at hand. However, since we've always shipped the `foo.lib` file, switching to `foo.def` would break 3rd parties build systems - something we would like to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

To produce an import library that is similar to the one generated by Microsoft's link.exe, you can use llvm-dlltool (part of the LLVM compiler project):

```
llvm-dlltool -m i386:x86-64 -d foo.def -l foo.lib
```

Substitute `i386:x86-64` for `i386` if you would like to create a 32-bit library. For more details see this answer to [How to generate an import library (LIB-file) from a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53838952/427545).

Note that some MinGW projects generate a .dll.a file (as produced by binutils dlltool). While this could be renamed to .lib and function as import library, I found that it would result in broken binaries if a MSVC projects links to multiple .dll.a libraries. So stick to llvm-dlltool instead for improved compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

> we'd like to cross-compile the entire thing on our linux systems

I'm not aware of any MS LIB clone portable to Linux, however `POLIB` from [Pelles C](http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc) distribution is free, small, self-contained and compatible with MS tool. It has no dependencies other than kernel32.dll, so, I believe, it will run under Wine too.