# How to add function to export table from static library?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, dynamic-linking, portable-executable

Suppose that we have `test.dll` which in fact consists of several static libraries `foo.lib`, `bar.lib` (they were written in `c/c++` and generated by `msvc` and have `pe/coff` formats).
I want to add functions from `foo.lib`, `bar.lib` to export table of `test.dll`. One of ways to export funcion is `declspec(dllexport)` specifier. But unfortunately it does not work for static library (because object files cannot have .edata section and linked dynamically). After compilation and linking we have `test.dll` which does not export functions at all. How can I solve this puzzle?

I did some research and I found out that usage of `def` file can solve this problem. But as I understand I should manually get list of mangled function names from `foo.lib`, `bar.lib` and insert the list to def file. It seems like hard way for me, maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946322/how-to-generate-an-import-library-lib-file-from-a-dll) about regenerating the DEF file from a DLL. Since `dumpbin` also understands .LIB files, the top answer should also work for you.

This is an automated process, so it will export everything, even stuff that's not really necessary.

Comment: How does dumpbin find exported functions from lib?  object files don't have edata section - I doubt that way will work (I'll checkout it)

Comment: @LmTinyToon: A `.lib` does not make a difference between exported and non-exported functions, so the question does not really make sense. `dumpbin` finds **all** functions, which is why I warn that this method will find and then **export all functions**