# How can I fix an error with the mex command linking to a dll

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, mex, fftw

This is my mex command:

```
currentDir = cd;currentDir = regexp(currentDir, filesep, 'split');
ipath = ['-I' fullfile(currentDir{1:end-1},'eigen-3.4.0')];

mex(ipath,lpathFFTW,...
    'CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -march=native -std=c++14 -fno-math-errno -ffast-math -fopenmp -DNDEBUG"',...
    'LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"',...
    'CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O3"',...
    'computeDASBMode.cpp','computeDAShelper.cpp',...
    '-outdir',outputFolder)
```

I've tried the following things as an option for lpathFFTW with the corresponding errors each trial gives:

**Trial 1:**
*where libfftw3-3.dll is in the target path*

```
lpathFFTW = ['-L' fullfile(currentDir{1:end-1},'fftw-3.3.5-dll64','libfftw3-3.lib')];
```

error:

```
Error using mex
C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_516976837146_11436\computeDAShelper.obj:computeDAShelper.cpp:(.text+0x128b): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename'
C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_516976837146_11436\computeDAShelper.obj:computeDAShelper.cpp:(.text+0x12f0): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_plan_many_dft'
C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_516976837146_11436\computeDAShelper.obj:computeDAShelper.cpp:(.text+0x135d): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Trial 2:**
*using the fftw library from matlab's root folder*

```
lpathFFTW = ['-L',fullfile(matlabroot,'bin',computer('arch'),'libmwfftw3.lib')];
```

error:

```
Error using mex
C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_1088299880810_11436\computeDAShelper.obj:computeDAShelper.cpp:(.text+0x128b): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_import_wisdom_from_filename'
C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_1088299880810_11436\computeDAShelper.obj:computeDAShelper.cpp:(.text+0x12f0): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_plan_many_dft'
C:\Users\nikun\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_1088299880810_11436\computeDAShelper.obj:computeDAShelper.cpp:(.text+0x135d): undefined reference to `__imp_fftw_export_wisdom_to_filename'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**TLDR:** I tried to compile a mex function linking the FFTW libraries using either the dll from fftw's website or the dll from matlab. Both seem to fail.

**Update**
I tried this in response to @Cris Luengo's comment:

```
lpathFFTW = ['-L',fullfile(matlabroot,'bin',computer('arch'))];

mex(ipath,lpathFFTW,'-llibmwfftw3.lib',...
    'CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -march=native -std=c++14 -fno-math-errno -ffast-math -fopenmp -DNDEBUG"',...
    'LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"',...
    'CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O3"',...
    'computeDASBMode.cpp','computeDAShelper.cpp',...
    '-outdir',outputFolder)
```

yielding the following error:

```
Error using mex
MEX cannot find library 'libmwfftw3', specified with the -l option.
 MEX searched for a file with one of the following names:
 libmwfftw3.lib
liblibmwfftw3.lib
 Verify the library name is correct. If the library is not
 on the existing path, specify the path with the -L option.
```

**Update 2**
I also tried this but got the following error:

```
lpathFFTW = ['-L',fullfile(matlabroot,'bin',computer('arch'))];

mex(ipath,lpathFFTW,...
    'CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -march=native -std=c++14 -fno-math-errno -ffast-math -fopenmp -DNDEBUG"',...
    'LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"',...
    'LINKLIBS="$LINKLIBS -llibmwfftw3"',...
    'CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O3"',...
    'computeDASBMode.cpp','computeDAShelper.cpp',...
    '-outdir',outputFolder,'-v')
```

```
C:/ProgramData/MATLAB/SupportPackages/R2020b/3P.instrset/mingw_w64.instrset/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibmwfftw3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `-L` is for the directory where the linker will look for library files. You also need to do `-l` (lowercase L) to specify which library to link to.

Comment: That makes sense and seems consistent with the documentation. However, I'm still getting an error where it can't seem to even find the library now.

Comment: It would typically be `-lmwfftw3` on Linux, not sure how that works on Windows. Do you have a `libmwfftw3.lib` file on your machine? If you only have a DLL file, you might have to provide the full file name, including extension? Again, not sure how this works on Windows.

Comment: I can't actually find a .lib file, just the .dll file. I've tried '-llibmwfftw3.dll' but the error message just looks like the error message from Update 1 but with 'libmwfftw3.dll.lib'. In other words, the mex command doesn't seem to recognize the .dll extension.

Comment: I also tried '-lmwfftw3' and the error message says it couldnt find mwfftw3.lib or libmwfftw3.lib. Clearly it should work, but for some reason the mex command isn't recognizing that it should check a shared library. Googling or searching how to use shared libraries with mex doesn't seem to help either..

Comment: You could create an import library (.lib) from your DLL. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9946322/7328782