# Is there a way for me to auto-generate a C++ .dll project based on DUMPBIN /Exports output?

Tags: c++, dll, man-in-the-middle

I've got an old game on my system that makes use of a few .dll's to compartmentalize some of it's behaviour. I'd like to Man-In-The-Middle the .dll's so that I can experiment with adding some functionality and fixing some broken behaviour, or at the very least breakpoint the flow of the application to work out why a certain bug is happening.

The DUMPBIN /Exports output is giving me things like:

> 3429  D64 00137450
> ?searchClosestDetNode@CPathAgent@MissionManagerSpace@@MEAAHHV?$Vector@$01N@Math@@@Z

Problem is, the .dll I'm interested in MITM'ing has about 1000 exported functions, so I really don't want to manually parse them all.

Is there an application I can feed this .dll into to autogenerate a MITM .dll that I can use to forward on the flow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946322/how-to-generate-an-import-library-lib-file-from-a-dll